# What does the sentence 'she had a salty hand' mean?

Tags: phrases, sentence

It is from the book *Crying in H Mart* by Michelle Zauner:

> She hated cilantro, avocados, and bell peppers. She was allergic to celery. She rarely ate sweets, with the exception of the occasional pint of strawberry Häagen-Dazs, a bag of tangerine jelly beans, one or two See’s chocolate truffles around Christmas time, and a blueberry cheesecake on her birthday. She rarely snacked or took breakfast. **She had a salty hand.**

I and the internet have no clue what it could possibly mean.

Comment: Cambridge dictionary has its informal meanings of the word 'salty': https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/salty

Comment: None of the informal idiomatic meanings *(angry, critical, coarse)* are relevant to the cited usage (from a "marginally" Anglophone writer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage has no currency among native Anglophones, but a number of people have *asked* about it online. And I'm pretty sure they're *all* asking about the same source (*Crying in H Mart* by Michelle Zauner).

I picked these three posts out from [the relevant Reddit page...](https://www.reddit.com/r/EnglishLearning/comments/ymd8h8/what_does_salty_hand_mean/)

> The phrase: “she has a salty hand” means to be a bit careful, not timid, but thinking of possible over-indulgence. You can have a “sweet hand” which would be an opposite.

> Even with the context, it’s basically impossible to guess what “salty hand” means here.
> We can tell that English is not the mother’s native language, and *the author makes a point of explaining how she misspeaks* and calls steaming hot “steamy hot.”  [**italics mine**]
> My guess is that “salty hand” is another misspoken expression. Maybe it’s apparent later what it means, maybe not.

> Since the author was born in Korea and raised in Oregon by a Korean mother and American father, I suspect that "a salty hand" might be a hybrid-English phrase stemming from the expression "a heavy hand with the salt." If she heard this growing up, she might not even realize it is not a standard English expression, especially if it's use was re-enforced by other members of a non-native community.

Comment: Ultimately, only the author can tell what that could mean.

Comment: Not necessarily - note the last sentence in my answer: *...especially if its use was re-enforced by **other members of a non-native community.***

Answer (score 1):

I interpret it in a very literal way.
She preferred salt over sweet: she favoured savoury, nourishing food, and steered away from confections and other foodstuffs of low nutritional value.

In fewer words: **she preferred nourishment over flavour**.

This idiom is probably the author's invention. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/EnglishLearning/comments/ymd8h8/what_does_salty_hand_mean/) is a Reddit thread with more people wondering about its meaning.

Comment: Thanks. I have gone through that page before posting this question here in the hope getting a better explanation.

Comment: I agree with your answer up to the colon, thereafter not so much.  I don't understand why you identify *savoury* and *nourishing*.  Have you never eaten a bucket of salted popcorn, nor pork scratchings, crisps, chips, many many savoury snacks which score very low on measures of nutritional value?

Comment: I'd say "she preferred salty to sugary" It might be the protagonist's  mangling of the English idiom "a sweet tooth".

Comment: 'In a [very] literal way' must mean that there was a fair bit of salt detectable on her hand, Joachim.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A very good point, thank you, Edwin. I'll make some edits.